# Wordpress "loop" not showing blog posts in my theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've made my first theme and it works great for editing updating pages etc, but won't display any posts.

I have put the "loop" in a template page (copied from twentytwelve theme), as I only want the posts to appear on that page. I've set the blog posts to appear on this page (from the settings page), but still nothing will show.

Here is my code for the template page to display blog posts.

Any idea what's wrong?

```
<?php
/**
*  Template Name: blog
*
* Full width page template with no sidebar.
*
* @package Myfirsttheme
* @subpackage Template
*/

get_header(); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
            <div class="entry-content">
                <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        <?php endif; // end current_user_can() check ?>

        </article><!-- #post-0 -->

    <?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Are you assigned this template to the page..Go to page and set Default Template to select in listed item...

Comment: two endif with one if??!!!

Comment: If this is the whole code you have, you should get blank page since you have <?php endif; // end current_user_can() check ?> but no if statement for that.

Answer (score 1):

Posts will always appear in the index.php template, unless you change the **"Front page displays"** option in `Settings=>Reading`, see here for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX5Bs.jpg If you have this set to show the blog posts on a page (is in the image), then whatever page that is (blog) has to have the Default Template (in the page edit screen) set to the value you wrote in the Template Name: section of your file (in your case blog), as Tamil said.

Updated: You have to echo `get_template_part()` or it won't show up. You can use `the_content()`  instead which is preferred. Any variables that start with the_ output themselves. The get_ variables don't output themselves.

```
<?php echo get_template_part(); ?>

<?php the_content() ?>
```